# Can the second "he spent" in this sentence be omitted?

Tags: grammar

I am certain that the time he spent in studying English is significantly more than that **he spent** in studying Japanese.

Comment: Reminder to answerers. **Please do not answer in comments.** Write a corroborated/justified answer where the question is on-topic. This helps the system keep track of questions which are actually unanswered. (And if a question is off-topic, vote to say so.)

Answer (score 1):

What English speakers would naturally do here to avoid repeating *spend* is not delete the second *he spent* but replace it with a form of the verb *do*, which for verbs plays the role that pronouns do for nouns.

> I am certain that the time he spent in studying English is significantly more than that he did in studying Japanese.

Actually, that sentence is a little awkward; you can rearrange it to get a sentence that sounds better:

> I am certain that he spent significantly more time in studying English than he did in studying Japanese.

(And you can delete all the occurrences of *in* in these sentences, although this doesn't address your question.)

Answer (score 0):

> I am certain that the time he spent in studying English is
> significantly more than that in studying Japanese

The omission of "he sent" in the second half of the sentence makes sense to me as native English speaker, but it sounds a bit strange. I would suggest the following re-write:

> I am certain that he spent significantly more time studying English
> than studying Japanese.

This suggestion allows you to only use "he spent" once.  Also, by moving "than" between "studying English" and "studying Japanese" the comparison is clearer.